# Confirming transaction with Solana/Web3.js

Tags: web3.js, transactions, sign, swap

I'm new to Solana development. I'm trying to create a simple token swap application in React js (not using ts). I have issue with confirming the transaction. The "@solana/wallet-adapter-react" is used to sign my transaction.

Here is the sample code:

```
//using Jupiter Station code for the swap
const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64');
var transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);

const signTrans = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize()
 
const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
  skipPreflight: true,
  maxRetries: 2
});

const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
 
await connection.confirmTransaction({
     blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
     lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
     signature: txid,
});
```

Not sure if this is correct -  signature: txid,

Essentially, it asks me to sign the transaction and then times out after some time.

Can you please help and steer me to the right direction?

UPD: here is the error to be exact

```
Signature 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 has expired: block height exceeded.
TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 has expired: block height exceeded.
    at Connection.confirmTransactionUsingBlockHeightExceedanceStrategy (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16151:15)
    at async Connection.confirmTransaction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15979:14)
    at async handleSwap (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:316:7)
```

UPD2: False alarm, I found a mistake:

```
   const signTrans = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
   const rawTransaction = signTrans.serialize()
```

I should of serialize signTrans instead of transaction.

I will keep it here in case somebody needs a sample code to sign and send the transcation.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your own question, then accept your self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const signTrans = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
const rawTransaction = signTrans.serialize()

const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
  skipPreflight: true,
  maxRetries: 2
});
```

I should have serialized `signTrans` instead of `transaction`.

I will keep it here in case somebody needs a sample code to sign and send the transaction.